# Prevent a listener from triggering itself

Tags: java, swt, listener

My issue today involves a simple contention in a JFace `TreeViewer` `Composite`. I'm trying to attach a `ControlListener` to the columns of my tree to enforce a minimum width. To do this, I'm watching every time that the column is resized and if the new width is too small, I impose the minimum onto it.

This is a GUI issue, but really it's something that could happen in any Java environment with a modification listener. I figured maybe some of you Java geeks out there might have fun with it.

```
    public static void getSizeControlListener(final TreeColumn column, final int minSize) {
        column.addControlListener(new ControlListener() {
            @Override
            public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                if(column.getWidth()<minSize) {
                    column.setWidth(minSize);
                }
            }
    });
```

One solution that works is to add a flag that gets set on entrance that any nested calls can reference and immediately exit if necessary. It works, but it's dirty and ugly.

```
    public static void getSizeControlListener(final TreeColumn column, final int minSize) {
        column.addControlListener(new ControlListener() {

            private boolean isRunning;

            @Override
            public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                if(isRunning)
                    return;
                isRunning = true;
                if(column.getWidth()<minSize) {
                    column.setWidth(minSize);
                }
                isRunning = false
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your solution with the flag is totally ok**, we use this pattern regularly to **prevent notification cascades**.
One example when such cascades occur is when synchronizing model-view states in MVC. Using such a flag allows us to realize cascade-free unidirectional updates with bidirectionaly synchronization.

The only difference to your implementation is that we use `try..finally` to make sure the flag is always reset (also when an exception occurs):

```
if (updating) {
    return;
}
try {
   updating=true;

   // do stuff

} finally {
   updating=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put below code in `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Runnable)`

```
column.setWidth(minSize);
```